# freeing up memory of Buffer instance in Node.js

Tags: node.js

node comes with abundance of method to create Buffers, but I haven't found one that dealocated the allocated piece of memory.

Do I just set buffer to null when I am done using it and let garbage collection kick in?

```
var buffer = new Buffer("pls dont null me");
buffer = null;
```

Comment: You don't even need to do that. Just let the variable fall out of scope and it will automatically be garbage collected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not care about it.
When you stop using the variable, the garbage collector will collect.
Just in case, its ok if you want to set null.

See the [buffer documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) in the Node.js site.